# Universal selector .on event handles does not bind?

Tags: jquery, events

just a little problem popping up:

```
$("*").on("click", function(event) {
if ($$(event.target).hasClass("disabled"))
{
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    return; 
}
});
```

is supposed to add an event to every element, which, if the element has the class 'disabled', is stopping the click event from being handled by any other eventhandler.

I thought this to be a very simple and basic application, however it seems to be working only on links, a-tag-elements, but not on any normal elements, which in my case simply keep handling click events.

I've tried a few variations, return false, stopImmediatePropagation etc, but with the same result.
What am I missing? Does it matter 'where' in my script I add this event handler? is there an execution order for bound event handlers or something?

Comment: this is extremely costly as there will be hundreds of handlers bounded to the document...

Comment: What about changing `$$(event.target)` to `$(event.target)`

Comment: also it will not handle any elements which are added after this code is executed

Comment: if that doesnt work,  `$("body").on("click", "*", function(event) {` might..

Comment: @JFit may not... what happens if there is a click handler binded directly to a element... then this handler will be called after the more direct once are called

Comment: You mean if the element is outside of body? @ArunPJohny It was only a suggestion really, I didnt test it.. (something to try)

Comment: @Arun, in that case even binding directly will not work either, because handlers are executed in the order they were registered. Subsequent handlers cannot interfere with handlers registered prior to them.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi yes... :(

Comment: $$(event.target) was a copy paste fluke, the code is $(event.target)
Yes, I am aware it will be costly, this is just development stage, I can narrow down the selectors once I got working code.

Comment: @user3154108 there is no easy way to do it... you need to make sure that this is the first click handler to be registered and then use `stopImmediatePropagation` also then it could work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple problems with what you're trying to do.

First, your code will only attach an event handler to elements that are *already on the page*, since those are the only elements that jQuery can select for the $("*") collection.

Second, as mentioned in the comments, your code will attach an event handler to every element on the page, which could be absurdly slow depending on how many elements are on that particular page.

Third, event handlers are executed in a certain order based on what element they are attached to (child element handlers are executed before parent event handlers) and in what order they are bound.

I can suggest three possible ways of doing this, depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish and how much of your code you're willing to change.

If you're just trying to make links and buttons that are disabled not work, then you could use [delegated](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) event handling to disable the default browser functionality.

```
$(document).on("click", "a, button", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

If you're trying to disable custom functionality that you've added to the page, then it might be better to add a global variable that is checked by all your other functions. This would require changing a lot of different pieces of code, which sometimes isn't feasible, but it might be nice to be able to turn off a page with just `var doAnything = false;`. Keep in mind that if you choose this way of doing things then the client will be easily able to turn functionality back on from the console.

The third way you could solve this would be to add a `:not(.disabled)` to each selector where you bind click events.

If you change this

```
$(".add").click(function(e) {
    // Do something
});
```

To this

```
$(".add:not(.disabled)").click(function(e) {
    // Do something
});
```

then that would work also.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating. My Intention is to make my own functionality which is bound to links, buttons but also spans and divs, easy to disabled and reenable based on the users input. There should be no relevant elements be added after the event handler is bound, so I was hoping to be able to use that. But I think I'm going to have to follow your second suggestion.

Comment: Putting the condition into every related click event worked out very well. I didn't use a global variable, though, but add or remove a certain class which I also use to style disabled elements. I don't even have to try and tinker with the event handlers themselves anymore. thanks a lot to everyone